# React 2 elements with props given by the same function causes any update of either element to affect the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the an app with the following format. The `sort_data` function is causing some very strange behavior that I would love to understand.

```
class App extends Component{
    ... 
    render(){return(
        <ChartInterface 
        row_data1={sort_data(this.getrow_data1())} 
        row_data2={sort_data(this.getrow_data2())}/>
        <Controls 
        change_data1={this.control_function1}
        change_data2={this.control_function2}/>
    )}

function ChartInterface(props){
    /* notice props.row_data2 is not used*/
    return <div>props.row_data1</div>
}


/*details*/
function sort_data(xdata){
    /* sorting algorithm that takes array of arrays of objects  
    and returns xdata but with the indexes were swapped based on
    element properties */ return xdata}
```

The `Controls` component has children which will sometimes call one of `control_function1` or `control_function2`. When called these functions invoke a `setState` in `App`, which changes some state variable (`this.state.x1` or `this.state.x2` depending on which function was called).

These state variables (`this.state.x1` and `this.state.x2`) determine the data returned by `this.getrow_data1()` and `this.getrow_data2()` respectively (i.e. `this.state.x2` ONLY affects `this.getrow_data2()`).

To clarify and summarize so far: `Controls` component causes state change in `App`, which changes the data passed as props to `<ChartInterface>`, and a new `<ChartInterface>` is created (as per my understanding).

My app uses a control component where users can select different data lists, and that data is fed back to `App`, and then to `<ChartInterface>`. OK.

If a change in `App`'s state causes getrow_data2 to return different data, that should not have an impact on the behavior of `ChartInterface` (it doesn't use `prop.row_data2` currently)

The weird part:

when `prop.row_data2` is changed by `getrow_data2`, the `return <div>row_data1</div>` in `ChartInterface` is actually returning `<div>row_data2</div>`.

This ONLY occurs when i have `this.getrow_data2()` wrapped in my `sort_data` function. 
i.e. if I initialize ChartInterface without `sort_data` the code behaves as expected.

```
        <ChartInterface 
        row_data1={this.getrow_data1()} 
        row_data2={this.getrow_data2()}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [React.Component's shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle function.
For example, for your `Controls` component:

```
...
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState) {
  return nextProps.control_function1 != this.props.control_function1
         || nextProps.control_function2 != this.props.control_function2;
}
```

This way, the component will not update if it receives an update event from its parent unless that update event changes specifically control_function1 or control_function2.

**Note:** If you have state in this component, make sure you account for that in the return by checking returning `true` if the state changed.